# style attribute in out.print()

Tags: jsp

```
 <table>
      <%
out.print("<tr style='border-bottom: dotted; border-top:dotted;border-color:black;'>");

            out.print("<td>");
            out.print("<font color='black'>"+message+"-");
            out.print("</td>");
            out.print("<td>");
            out.print("<font color='blue'>"+name);
            out.print("</td>");
            out.print("</tr>");



      %>
  </table>
```

the content is getting displayed....but the style attribute in tr tag is not working.
i am creating a post commment module.....when users post comment i want to show dotted lines above and below it.....the same way as we have on this website

Comment: I'm not sure how this can work at all -- you have `</table>` in your scriptlet. This scriplet also has a mismatched `}`, although that may be balanced elsewhere... Also you are not closing your `<font>` tags. look

Comment: Using `out.print()` in JSP is extremely poor practice. Just write HTML plain in JSP and use EL `${}` to inline dynamic variables.

Comment: Please also stop reposting the same question over and over. This is the third: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203525/unable-to-use-style-in-out-print-closed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203274/unable-to-put-style-attribute-in-out-print. If you want to improve the question, just use `edit` link. If you can't find your questions back, click your username in the top bar, it will lead to your user profile where all your questions are http://stackoverflow.com/users/606824/prerna.

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't solve your problem, but `</table>` is inside your <% %> tags.